# pgfplots table read handle non-numerical entries

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplotstable

In a previous [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/213183/66600), I asked how to create a Root Locus plot and got a pretty good answer thanks to @percusse using `\pgfplotstableread` that gets me 90% of the way there. However, the one thing I need to handle to properly plot such a graph is to handle the cases where the roots go off to infinite (vs. when they terminate at some finite zero, which currently gets handled correctly).

The matlab output gives me the following table which I am using:

```
pr1  pi1  pr2  pi2  pr3  pi3  pr4  pi4   k
  0    0   -1    0   -2    1   -2   -1    0
... % More numbers
 Inf   0   Inf   0   Inf   0   Inf   0   Inf
```

Of which you can see the last lines will (sometimes) end in "Inf".

`\pgfplotstableread` will throw out this result when creating plots as follows:

`NOTE: coordinate (Inf,0) has been dropped because it is unbounded (in x). (see
also unbounded coords=jump).`

I would like to handle this last row entry and make a decision to either place a circle at the last spot (if it is not infinite) or somehow indicate that this root is going to infinite, either by simply placing an arrow indicating the direction it's going off into, or by extending the line to (near) the plot boundaries.

Here is the modified code I got from my other thread:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\pgfplotstableread{prob3.txt}\tablea

\begin{tikzpicture}[
%This is to provide the start  point cross marker 
start marker/.pic={\draw (-#1,-#1) -- (#1,#1) (#1,-#1)--(-#1,#1);}
]
  % Don't put any markers, limit the visible area from one side, draw grid
  \begin{axis}[no marks,grid=both,width=\linewidth]
  \pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\tablea}
  \pgfmathparse{\pgfplotsretval-2} % 1 for K and 1 for extra length
  \pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult/2} % Real and Imag part for each
  \foreach \x in{1,...,\pgfmathresult}{ % Iterate over the columns of the table
    \addplot+[] table[x=pr\x,y=pi\x] {\tablea} % Draw the curves
    % Put the ending marker with size adjusted to 2pt
    node[draw,circle,inner sep=2pt] at (current plot end) {}
    pic at (current plot begin) {start marker=2pt};%Put the starting marker
  }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Which produces the following plot

[image: Root Locus Plot]

Using this exact data (prob3.txt):

```
pr1     pi1     pr2     pi2     pr3     pi3     pr4     pi4     k
0       0       -1      0       -2      1       -2      -1      0
-0.043035       0       -0.9    0       -2.0285 1.0103  -2.0285 -1.0103 0.1989
-0.14648        0       -0.70634        0       -2.0736 1.0295  -2.0736 -1.0295 0.55456
-0.37852        0       -0.40764        0       -2.1069 1.0459  -2.1069 -1.0459 0.85374
-0.39299        0       -0.39299        0       -2.107  1.0459  -2.107  -1.0459 0.8546
-0.3929 0.014558        -0.3929 -0.014558       -2.1071 1.046   -2.1071 -1.046  0.85545
-0.32759        0.39389 -0.32759        -0.39389        -2.1724 1.0824  -2.1724 -1.0824 1.5462
-0.3132 0.43556 -0.3132 -0.43556        -2.1868 1.0911  -2.1868 -1.0911 1.719
-0.29944        0.47216 -0.29944        -0.47216        -2.2006 1.0996  -2.2006 -1.0996 1.8917
-0.27357        0.53465 -0.27357        -0.53465        -2.2264 1.1162  -2.2264 -1.1162 2.2373
-0.22727        0.63256 -0.22727        -0.63256        -2.2727 1.1475  -2.2727 -1.1475 2.9285
-0.15017        0.77197 -0.15017        -0.77197        -2.3498 1.2035  -2.3498 -1.2035 4.3109
Inf     0       Inf     0       Inf     0       Inf     0       Inf
```

I also noticed that the last set of columns (`pr4/pi4`) are not getting plotted. Any ideas there could help too (probably something to do with it not plotting past y = -0.8)

Comment: If you want to mark a code block you can simply leave 4 spaces in the beginning of each line. Or select the code and click the `{}` button at the top (Ctrl+K is the shortcut)